# How can I make Compiz work with MATE 1.6?

Tags: compiz, mate

I'm using MATE 1.6 from the official MATE APT repo.

I've tried enabling Compiz using the following steps, based on [this guide](http://www.tuxgarage.com/2012/05/run-mate-with-compiz-in-ubuntu.html) and adapted for MATE 1.6:

1. Open dconf editor
2. Go to `org.mate.desktop.session.required-components`
3. Change `windowmanager` from `marco` to `compiz`
4. Relogin

However, when I relogin, I have no window frames and no Compiz plugins. I've tried `compiz --replace` in a terminal, which gives no errors, only logs of it loading plugins.

Comment: just do this and be happy with Compiz
[How to install Compiz on ubuntu and MATE Linux MInt](http://l4l.su/effects/7-how-to-install-compiz-on-ubuntu-and-mate-linux-mint.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATE 1.6 will not work with Compiz, the change from Mateconf to Gsettings broke it.
Use MATE 1.4 if you want to use Compiz with MATE

Comment: can you explain *why* compiz doesn't work with 1.6?

Comment: Read through the MATE forums, you will find the confusing answers of the devs there. Seems MATE using Gsettings is not able to communicate with compiz anymore thus it will not find window decorators and compiz plugins. I tried MATE 1.6 with Compiz 0.8.8, as soon as compi geht's kicked in I lose all panels and end up with a dysfunctional system.

Comment: Somehow when I upgraded from 1.4 to 1.6 it imported my Compiz settings, and although it was glitchy at the first one or two logons, I'm using MATE 1.6 with wobbly windows as of now. In dconf I have at org.mate.session.required-components --- windowmanager=compiz. I have tried Compiz Fusion Icon but it crashed with 1.6.

Comment: You also have to make sure that the relevant plugins are enabled in CompizConfig Settings Manager, such as Window Decoration (mine is with command gtk-window-decorator --replace), Window Move, Window Resize, and of coarse Cube rotation.

Answer (score 5):

Just tried this and worked for me:

> 1. Use Synaptic or Apt in terminal (sudo apt-get install) to install the following packages: compiz, libdecoration0-dev,
>      compizconfig-settings-manager, compiz-plugins Do not bother to install
>      install the fusion-icon package, Compiz Fusion Icon doesn’t work
>      anymore in Mate 1.6
> 2. To set-up compiz to start automatically at login go to Start-up Applications (from Control Centre and add a new entire (click add) and
>      write "Compiz" to name and enter "compiz --replace" in the command
>      field (without the quotes). For  manually start use command "compiz
>      --replace" in terminal.
> 3. Replace "marco" with "compiz" windowmanager to lower the CPU usage. Do this with dconf Editor (install it first). Navigate to org > mate >
>      desktop > session > required-components > windowmanager, click on
>      “marco” and modify it. You can use also next command in terminal: sudo
>      gsettings set org.mate.desktop.session.required-components
>      windowmanager compiz
> 4. Open CompizConfig Settings Manager and be sure you ticked “Window Decoration”, “Move Window”and any other functions you may find useful.
> 5. Go to General section, check "Gnome Compatibility", open it and  go to Commands tab and replace (in all 3 command lines) the word "gnome"
>      with 'mate". Go back and test this: press Prt Sc key.  Now you can
>      take a dessktop screenshot.
>
> Activating composition you may experience some freezing or resets of
>   the X system due to the video card. Tray to change your video driver.
>   Works for me.

Source: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1298

Comment: what was missing for is `libdecoration0-dev`, also I got fooled and didn't realise everything in compiz-settings-manager was turned (window decoration, desktop wall, move window, application switcher) - its all working now, cheers

Answer (score 3):

I know you have already marked an answer, but I was having the same problem as you and found a solution. All you need to do is:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-gnome
```

This installs **gtk-window-decorator** for you which is used by compiz to draw the window borders. Logout and log back in and you'll see you have window decorations again :)

Worked for me on Linux Mint 15 Olivia Mate.

Considering Mint 15 is [based of Ubuntu 13.04](http://linuxmint.com/rel_olivia.php), this shouldn't be hard to perform on Ubuntu ;)

Comment: If someone tries on Ubuntu I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @strugee, just tried this using Ubuntu 14.04, and it does not work. Or at least, it doesn't just automatically work as described in this answer. I have Mate and compiz-gnome installed, and so far Compiz does not work in Mate.